# Is it possible to give custom date format for jQuery datapicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want a date format like **Jan  5, 2015** using datepicker plugin. But, right now what most I can do after referring the documentation is to give this format **dd-mm-yy**. Is it possible to display it in above mentioned format(Jan  5, 2015) when someone selects a date in UI

Comment: What datepicker you're talking about exactly? The one from jQuery UI? Than have a look at https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats and http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: I'm using [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but with **default functionality**

Comment: Which datepicker exactly? There are hundreds, if not thousands, of them ;) - https://www.google.de/search?q=jquery+datepicker

Comment: I already mentioned a link in my comment above. BTW I'm using jQuery UI datepicker

Comment: I missed that, sry. But if you'd mentioned it in the question... ;) Then have a look at the links from my first comment.

Comment: Ya it works, if you answer it then I can select it as correct :-)

Comment: You can answer your own question as well :) I've just c&p the links from the docu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Andreas** help, I found following date formats can be used with [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats):

```
mm/dd/yy
yy-mm-dd (positions of dd, mm, yy can be altered for diff O/P)
d M, y
d MM, y
DD, d MM, yy
```

More [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

Hope it helps someone else too.